# How to set on click listener for figure tag?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onclicklistener, figure

I have the following simple html doc:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <figure>
        <object class="" type="image/svg+xml" data="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"></object>
    </figure>
</body>

<script>
    var figures = document.querySelectorAll('figure')
    for (let figure of figures) {
        figure.addEventListener("click", function () {
            console.log("hello")
        })
    }
</script>

</html>
```

However, nothing happens when I click on the image. Is it possible to set an on click listener for a figure tag, and if not, what are the alternatives I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the `figure` but the [`object` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object). This tag runs in a nested context that doesn't propagate events back to the parent; therefore, when you click on the figure loaded by the object it doesn't fire back from the embedded object never reaching the click on your `figure`.

> The [`object` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) is meant to run embedded applications (flash apps back in the day) so it has an abnormal behaviour similar to `iframe`, there are a lot of security concerns.

You can use an `img` to load your `svg` instead of an object, it will load the same way and this does fire the event back to the parent, hence, triggering the click on the parent `figure`.

```
<figure>
  <img width="100" height="100" src="./path/to/img.svg">
</figure>
```

Bellow there is a snippet showing the different behaviour when using `object` and `img` to load an image, the second triggers the click.

```js
var figures = document.querySelectorAll('figure')
for (let figure of figures) {
  figure.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("hello")
  })
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption>I'm an object and I don't propagate events back to my parent</figcaption>
  <object width="100" height="100" type="image/svg+xml" data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg"></object>
</figure>

<figure>
  <figcaption>I'm an img and I propagate events back to my parent</figcaption>
  <img width="100" height="100" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg">
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event handler to the `figure` element just as you would any other element. There is a chance that your figure element isn't present in the DOM when your JavaScript runs and tries to bind the click event. One thing to try is to make sure your figures array is coming back as you would expect. The other thing to look at is in your `for of` loop that your `figure` variable is what you would expect.

```js
const myFigure = document.querySelector('#myFigure');
myFigure.onclick = (evt) => {
  console.log('I was just clicked');
}
```

```html
<figure id="myFigure">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var figures = document.getElementsByTagName('figure');
for (let i = 0; i < figures.length; i++) {
    figures[i].onclick = function (e) {
        console.log("hello from figure: " + i);
    };
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" />
</figure>
<br><br>
<figure>
  <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" />
</figure>
<br><br>
<figure>
  <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" />
</figure>
<br><br>
<figure>
  <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" />
</figure>
```